# How to show check mark in checkbox when using an Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Let's say I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display an alert when checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
      alert("check");
    } else {
       alert("not check");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is as soon as I click the checkbox, it will show the alert message BUT it doesn't give it a chance to also show the check mark in the checkbox.  I DO want it to be an alert and I DO want it to do that as soon as user selects a checkbox but I ALSO want to see the checkmark in chekcbox.

I does work in IE 11 but it does not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this with a short `setTimeout` like so:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");

  setTimeout(function() {
    alert(checkBox.checked ? "check" : "not checked");
  }, 10);
}
```

```html
<p>Display an alert when checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
```